# ssh-agent running with i3wm keeps promting for password at each git push

Tags: linux, ssh, git, ssh-agent, i3-window-manager

I have installed Debian testing with [i3wm](https://i3wm.org), using [SDDM (Simple Desktop Display Manager)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SDDM) to start it. In the i3 workspace, I could find the ssh-agent process already started. However, I still am being prompted to input my key passphrase everytime I do a git push to github (the remote is `git@github.com:user/repo.git`). See below for the details. Any way to prevent this from happening?

I have already added my `id_rsa` to my ssh-agent.

```
$ cat /proc/version 
(Linux version 4.1.0-2-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.9.3 (Debian 4.9.3-3) ) #1 SMP Debian 4.1.6-1 (2015-08-23))

$ i3 --version
i3 version 4.10.3 (2015-07-30, branch "4.10.3") © 2009-2014 Michael Stapelberg and contributors

$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.9p1 Debian-1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015

$ apt-cache info sddm
Package: sddm
Version: 0.11.0-3
```

I successfully tested this SSH connection with `ssh -v -T git@github.com` and it looks fine:

```
ssh -v -T git@github.com
OpenSSH_6.9p1 Debian-1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.130] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9p1 Debian-1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa': 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([192.30.252.130]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
Hi user! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3252, received 1776 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 59136.9, received 32296.2
debug1: Exit status 1
```

And here is the output of `git remote show origin`:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa': 
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@github.com:user/repo.git
  Push  URL: git@github.com:user/repo.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
master pushes to master (up to date)
```

Comment: Problem still persists.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I execute `ssh-add` in my i3 config file. This way, I am prompted for my passphrase on startup, after which I can use the key without being prompted again.

Don't know what your setup is (how you add your key to the agent or if you use gnome keyring or something), but this may be an option for you, too.

Comment: Okay, I can imagine that way of solving it. But I have logged in to i3 by entering my user password from the SSDM login manager (provided by KDE5). Any way to add those keys WITHOUT entering the key passwords? I recall that some keychain programs can use the user login password as a master password then automatically add all keys.